# MATLAB- Plotting points to 3D vector plot

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I currently have this plot:

[image]

The goal is to get a plot like this:
[image]

I plotted the vectors using

```
for idx = 1:size(starts,1)
    q=quiver3(starts(idx,1), starts(idx,2), starts(idx,3), ends(idx,1), ends(idx,2), ends(idx,3), ...
        'Color', RGBofStainVector(idx,:));
    hold on
end
```

I have a 12x3 matrix with X,Y,Z points and would want to plot them in the same graph.
How can I add the different 3D points with their respective color as seen in picture 2? I tried using plot3 and scatter3 functions but had no luck.

Comment: Use plot3 https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html and simply plot those points.